# Error in aeqSurv(Y) : aeqSurv exception, an interval has effective length 0

Tags: r, exception, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I'm using R's `coxph` function to fit a survival regression model, and I'm trying to model time dependent covariates (see [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf)). When fitting the model, I get the following error:

`Error in aeqSurv(Y) : 
  aeqSurv exception, an interval has effective length 0`

Other than the source code, I couldn't find any references to this error online. Would appreciate any ideas about how to handle this exception.

Comment: If you could provide the `Surv` object via `dput` I trust you could get some help. The error sound to me like for some events `time == time2`:`Surv(time, time2, event...)`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I had code which was working fine for years and I even had workspaces saved that, when I ran the models, worked fine. But recently I've been getting this error as well. Has something changed in the coxph or Surv functions?

Comment: Looks like this error arises with R v. 3.4.3. When I downgraded to version 3.3.3 everything worked again. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 4):

I found the same error. Probably the cause is the aeqSurv routine that treats time values such that tiny differences are treated as a tie. This is actually useful and the error is potentially pointing an issue with the data.

However, if we need to force a solution you can use the coxph.options.
Just setting timefix = FALSE in the call to coxph should make the trick!

Source:
https://rdrr.io/cran/survival/src/R/aeqSurv.R

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after I used the `survSplit` function to make time intervals, prior to fitting with `coxph`. I noticed that `survSplit` introduced trailing digits (i.e., 20 days turned into 20.0 days). So I removed those digits with the `round` function and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Like the above answer, adding the control variable in the `coxph` function should solve the problem. Please see the reference: https://github.com/therneau/survival/issues/76

```
model <- coxph(formula = Surv(time1, time2, event) ~ cluster(cluster), 
               data = dataframe, 
               control = coxph.control(timefix = FALSE)) # add the control variable
```